# Pass function inside string literal to other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to pass a function defined in my actions to an element.

Reducer

```
case 'UPDATE_HEADER':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        headerChildren: state.headerChildren.concat([action.child])
    });
```

Action.js

```
export const deleteHeader = () => {
    return {
        type: 'DELETE_HEADER',
    };
}
```

I am passing this action to my sidebar

```
onAddHeader () {
    this.props.addHeader();
    this.props.updateHeader(
        `<Header key='${this.props.childKey}' 
             deleteHeader='${this.props.deleteHeader}'/>`,
    );
}
```

The deleteHeader function is being passed to the Header component but the problem is that it is being passed as a string and not as a function.

I am rendering it as this

```
`{this.props.headerChildren.map((value, index) => (
    <JsxParser
        key={index}
        components={[Header]}
        jsx={value}
    />
))}`
```

Can someone please guide me through the solution. I have searched a lot and couldn't find a way to do it. If this is not the correct approach to do so, kindly let me know the proper way to do it. I am new to React + Redux so finding it a bit difficult.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to take a stab at guessing what I think you want to achieve here - it is a bit unclear so if I am wrong please feel free to comment and I can try and fix.

You don't need to use a string template if you are not trying to pass a string. You can simply pass the component and props themselves. Something like this...

```
// I'm assuming you're doing something like this 
import Header from './wheverYourHeaderIs';

...

onAddHeader () {
    this.props.addHeader();
    this.props.updateHeader(Header, 
       { key: this.props.childKey, 
         deleteHeader: this.props.deleteHeader 
       }
    );
}
```

I turned your props into 1 keyed object so it is flexible to add more/less props without having to modify the number of arguments your `updateHeader` function has to take.

Then your `updateHeader` would do something like :

```
 function updateHeader(Component, props) {

  // do whatever you were going to do with your component
     <Component {...props} />
  // becasue we combined props into one object 
  // this is the same as <Header key={this.props.childKey} deleteHeader={this.props.deleteHeader}/> 
 }
```

Not sure if this is what you were trying to achieve please feel free to comment if not.

Comment: The issue using this is, `updateHeader` function takes one parameter which here is Header and stores it in an headerComponents array as a string. Then, I use it to map through all the headerComponents and parse them using

`{this.props.headerChildren.map((value, index) => (
                        <JsxParser
                            key={index}
                            components={[Header]}
                            jsx={value}
                        />
                    ))}`

Comment: @leoc1f3r why does it have to be stored as a string? Assuming when you say [header] there you mean the *actual* component in which case you need the component, not the string. Furthermore if you're trying to parse the jsx component you would need to pull it out first, no? A react component is a function itself.

Comment: I tried storing it as Components itself but the issue was the reducer wasn't able to recognize it as a react component and was not able to render it. I wasn't able to find any solution for this.

Comment: @leoc1f3r You can pass components as arguments - they are just functions themselves. Just make sure you pass Header, not <Header />. Also, the reducers just update the state - it shouldn't care what it is, you are just passing it to props/state/whatever.

Comment: I will update my question with other parts of the code. Kindly let me know if you can help me with it

Comment: @leoc1f3r yeah my answer still stands - *it is being parsed as a string because you are passing it as a string* . You can solve this any way you feel most comfortable doing it, pass the actual component, `Header`, and **not** a string. If you want to keep the `updateHeader` as one argument I would send it an object with keys like `{ component: Header, props: ...props}`. Also **are you sure you need a jsx parser here?** - are you just trying to pass a component  into an array  and then and render it? If so there is no need for a jsx parser.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use $ or single quotes when passing props these kind of props.. You just need to enclose the value to be evaluated in {}.. It is only when you need to pass a string literal do you use single quotes.

So use something like this instead

`<Header key={this.props.childKey} deleteHeader={this.props.deleteHeader}/>`

Comment: This is the props I am getting in Header according to your suggestion
`Key"{this.props.childKey}"`

`deleteheader:"{this.props.deleteHeader}/"`

Comment: "$ is never used in react afaik" => $ used here is not related to jquery. It is a  es6 syntax for writting expressions in string https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @Prakash My apologies.I didn't realize that.. That usage didn't strike me when I answered.. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @leoc1f3r Could you please tell me why you're passing a component to this.props.updateHeader()?? What does that function do?

Comment: @JiN `this.props.updateHeader` renders Header component from the sidebar to the content section dynamically. updateHeader keeps a count of the total number of headers that I have and passes them to a JSX parser which renders it to the content section along with the props passed with it inside the template literal.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the required props that are needed to render the header as the arguments to updateHeader and then make the updateHeader return a Header component..